# condition based select SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For example I have a table "Info" as below.

```
+--------+------------+------+------------+
| Entity | Department | Code | Code_count |
+--------+------------+------+------------+
| E1     | D1         |  123 |          5 |
| E1     | D1         |  234 |         10 |
| E1     | D1         |  345 |         20 |
| E1     | D2         |  456 |          2 |
| E1     | D2         |  567 |          5 |
| E1     | D2         |  678 |         10 |
+--------+------------+------+------------+
```

My query should function like this: for each `Entity` and `Department` pair, select the `code` which has the `maximum code count`.

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
join
(
  select entity, department, max(Code_count) as Code_count 
  from your_table
  group by entity, department
) t2 on t1.entity = t2.entity 
    and t1.department = t2.department 
    and t1.Code_count = t2.Code_count
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT ENTITY, DEPARTMENT, CODE
FROM TABLE
WHERE CODE_COUNT IN (
  SELECT MAX(CODE_COUNT) FROM TABLE GROUP BY ENTITY, DEPARTMENT)
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/482397/12

Answer (score 0):

use `Window Function` to get the result.

```
SELECT Row_number()OVER(
                       partition BY Entity, Department
                       ORDER BY Code_count DESC) RN,
                   *
            FROM   table_name
```

`partition BY` Divides the query result set into partitions. The window function is applied to each partition separately and computation restarts for each partition.

```
SELECT Entity,
       Department,
       Code,
       Code_count
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(
                   partition BY Entity, Department
                   ORDER BY Code_count DESC) RN,
               *
        FROM   table_name) A
WHERE  rn = 1
```